# Inductor type: LR Low-pass filter

Tags: audio, filter, inductor, low-pass

Is it a common practice to use unshielded inductors for LR networks in audio applications?
I need to include a 1st order LPF for the output of a DAC. I found many inexpensive unshielded 10mH inductors selling online, reportedly intended for power supplies, and I wonder if they can be used for audio line applications. No idea how EMI pickup would affect it, but since audio current is very low I'm guessing it shouldn't be a problem.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a link to the inductor's data sheet and manufacturer's site.

Comment: LR lowpasses for audio bandwidth are rather unusual, and end up with large power draw or huge inductors. RC lowpasses are more usual. LR might be worth it, if you are after esoterically low noise, but before going that length, make a custom DAC with sufficiently low noise.

Comment: If *audio current is very low*, then currents caused by stray magnetic fields may be significant. If your intention is a low-pass filter, these inductors tend to be more sensitive to high frequency stray fields (above audio)...defeating your intention of suppressing high frequencies. I see these types used at much higher currents than line-level audio.

Comment: To be clear, active RC filters are more common than LC, partly for cost, size, and noise concerns like this.

Comment: @glen_geek The lower the current going through the inductor, the more prone it becomes to pick up high fq noises from other sources? Main reason I want this is that it will take minimal space on my build, since a resistor to ground is already there right after the DAC.

Comment: Probably not the best plan - with the type you have pictured, you'll pick up hum from power lines, which are in the audio range and presumably in the range of your low-pass filter.

Comment: @Domingo , You *might* make it work, but you should be prepared for revisions - a fully enclosed magnetic path inductor might be needed, especially in tight spaces where noisy logic or a switcher supply is nearby - seems like you don't have much control over adjacent space. An amplifier after this LPF might make even small noise pick-up audible, and objectionable. Your audio quality requirements are unknown.